# Scrapy: how to use multiple spiders in one redis queue

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm learning scrapy-redis,I have multiple spiders in one scrapy-redis project.How can I smart control every spider start and stop?And it's smart to use multiple spiders in one project just for every spider to share a setting?
My code is like this

```
from scrapy_redis.spiders import RedisSpider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class MySpider1(RedisSpider):
...

class MySpider2(RedisSpider):
...

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(MySpider1)
process.crawl(MySpider2)
process.start()
```

I have to lpush start_url to every spider,it's inconvenient.Is there any smart way to control it？

Comment: You need to form a clear question here - it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @Granitosaurus Sorry,I have update my question,I hope my question now is clear.